# Wrong choices in my choices list

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

With symfony 2.7, I have two differents forms in my webpage :

**Form 1 :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    /*
        $choices = array(
            0 => A (entity "Personne"),
            1 => B  (entity "Personne")
        )
     * 
     */
    $builder
        ->add('personne', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LogicielBundle:Personne',
            'choices' => $choices,
            'label' => 'Banque'
        ))
    ;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'logiciel_remise_selection_form';
}
```

**Form 2**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    /*
        $choices = array(
            3 => C (entity "Personne"),
            4 => D (entity "Personne")
        )
     * 
     */
    $builder
        ->add('personne', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LogicielBundle:Personne',
            'choices' => $choices,
            'label' => 'Banque'
        ))
    ;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'logiciel_remise_form';
}
```

**My Controller :**

```
    $form1 = $this->createForm('logiciel_remise_selection_form', null);
    $this->submit($form1);
    if($form1->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $remise = new Remise;
        $form2 = $this->createForm('logiciel_remise_form', $remise);
    }
```

But in my webpage is < select >, for "form2", I have choices **A and B** ... **it is the choice of "form1"** O_o

When I dump() my "form2", I have choices **C and D** (good choices) but I have same "IdReader" in **choices_list** *(I do not know what it is)* with "form1" ( https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php )

Can you help me ?

Comment: Why (in your controller) you check if is valid `$form`variable instead of `$form1`??

Comment: Just copy / paste error (for simplification) :)

Comment: show your view please